# IntelliJ gradle test runner ignores jvmArgs defined in Test tasks in gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I apply in gradle (kotlin dsl) the following configuration for all Test tasks for all projects:

```
tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  jvmArgs(
    "--add-opens",
    "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens",
    "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "--add-opens",
    "java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "-Xshare:off",
  )
  maxParallelForks = 1
}
```

when I run from a terminal all tests pass.

When I configure in IntelliJ: Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Run tests using: Intellij IDEA and run tests I get the error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private static java.time.Instant java.time.Instant.create(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @45c8e616
```

- Java 17
- Kotlin 1.8.10
- Gradle 8.0.2
- IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)

Answer (score 0):

- Use either Gradle runner in IntelliJ IDEA: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Run tests using:** set to  **Gradle**
- or add JVM arguments into JUnit Run configuration manually:
  [image]